# Question on combining diagrams

Tags: plotting, graphics

I tried to put a zigzag line within a plot that here is a Streamplot.

However, I failed to combine the figures using Show command.

Would you be so kind as to let me know what is the problem?

I want to put the zigzag line from (x=0,y=0) to (x=0,y=10) within the figure.

```
s1 := StreamPlot[{1/(x + 1), 1/(y + 1)}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}]
s2 := Rotate[Graphics[Line[Table[{n, (-1)^n}, {n, 120}]]], 90 Degree]
Show[{s1, s2}]
```

Comment: Only two `Graphics` can be combined. `s2` has head `Rotate`, not `Graphics`. Apply `Rotate` only to the contents of `Graphics`, not `Graphics` itself.

Comment: Since you signed your post anyway, please consider setting a username. "user14750" is very hard to distinguish from any other "userXXXXX".

Comment: related: [search results - Rotate + Show](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/search?q=Show+Rotate)

Answer (score 1):

Try giving the `Epilog` option to your stream plot.

```
StreamPlot[{1/(x + 1), 1/(y + 1)}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1},
  Epilog -> Rotate[Line[Table[{n, (-1)^n}, {n, 120}]/120], 90 °, {0, 0}]]
```

[image: plot]

#### Notes

1. you must use the 3rd argument of `Rotate` to specify you want the zigzag line rotated about the origin and not the default center of the line.
2. You must also scale your zigzags by dividing by 120.

Of course, it can also be done by combining the stream plot with a correctly specified graphic using `Show`.

```
s1 = StreamPlot[{1/(x + 1), 1/(y + 1)}, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}];
s2 = 
  Graphics @ Rotate[Line[Table[{n, (-1)^n}, {n, 120}]/120], 90 °, {0, 0}];
Show[{s1, s2}]
```

This produces the same image as the previous code.

Comment: Thank you so much for your helpful comments.